# How is this summation equal to this fraction?

Tags: probability, statistics, summation

I am looking at my teacher's solutions for a Statistics problem and he's made the following equivalence. I am not sure why he did this, if it helps, we're doing probability with the geometric distribution.

$$\sum_{x=21}^\infty  (.2)(.8)^{x-1} = .2\frac{.8^{21-1}}{1-.8}$$

If needed, the geometric distribution formula is the following:

$$p(y)=p(1-p)^{(y-1)}$$

Comment: Look at the standard formula for summing a geometric series.

Comment: @BruceET Ah, I see now. This would be an infinite series though correct?

Comment: Yes, it is.  The upper limit of the sum is $\infty$

Comment: Makes a lot more sense now, had completely forgotten about this formula, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint #1:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ar^k = a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ar^k = \frac{a}{1-r}$$

Hint #2:

Subtract.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Compare

$$\sum_{x=21}^\infty  (0.2)(0.8)^{x-1} = (0.2)(0.8)^{21-1}+\sum_{x=22}^\infty  (0.2)(0.8)^{x-1}$$

and

$$(0.8)\sum_{x=21}^\infty  (0.2)(0.8)^{x-1}=\sum_{x=22}^\infty  (0.2)(0.8)^{x-1}.$$